# Is it possible to turn off the screen after 15 or 30 minutes on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using the latest iOS 14.2.  Sometimes, I have some notes or some game that I want to leave open for a while, such as 15 minutes or half an hour, without the screen turning off.

Right now, it is either 5 minutes or never, so if it is 5 minutes, then I have to keep on operating the iPhone to wake it up every 5 minutes.  If I set it to Never, then I have the risk of putting it aside, and fell asleep or went somewhere, and then wake up with 100% battery running down to 0%.  Is there a way to make it or tweak it to more of a "moderate" or medium term, such as 15 minutes or 30 minutes?

Comment: Still no way natively on iPhone. On iPad, you can set it to 15min.

Answer (score 3):

There's no setting higher than 5 minutes except the "Never" setting. So no, you cannot set it to 15 or 30 minutes with the current iOS software.

Note that the certain apps block turning the screen off while they're running. For example if you're playing a movie in Netflix.